# Translate zend framework 1 form labels and error message

Tags: zend-framework

I have a web site which is in English and Arabic. I converted the text into Arabic but the form labels and error message is not converting. I am using gettext adapter and how do i convert this labels. I am using Zend_Form and creating object of this form and passign this to view.

**Bootstrap file**

```
protected function _initTranslate() {
    $translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext', APPLICATION_PATH . "/lang/", null, array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY));
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $registry->set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
    //Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
    $translate->setLocale('ar');
}

public function _initRoutes() {
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $this->_frontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');
    $router = $this->_frontController->getRouter();


    $langRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':lang', array(
        'lang' => 'ar',
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
            ), array(
        'lang' => 'en|ar'
            )
    );


    $defaultRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':controller/:action', array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
            )
    );



    $defaultRoute = $langRoute->chain($defaultRoute);

    $router->addRoute('langRoute', $langRoute);
    $router->addRoute('defaultRoute', $defaultRoute);
}

protected function _initLanguage() {
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Language());
}
```

**Form**

```
class Application_Form_Contactus extends Zend_Form {

public function init() {
    // Set the method for the display form to POST
    $this->setMethod('post');


    $this->addElement('text', 'name', array('label' => 'Name', 'class' => 'inputbox',
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
        'required' => true));

    // Add an email element

    $this->addElement('text', 'email', array('label' => 'Email', 'class' => 'inputbox', 
        'required' => true, 'filters' => array('StringTrim'), 'validators' => array('EmailAddress')));



    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
        'required' => false,
        'label' => 'Send',
        'value' => 'save',
        'class' => 'submit-but',
        'attribs' => array('type' => 'submit'),
    ));

   }  
}
```

**Controller**

```
$form = new Application_Form_Contactus();
    $form->setAction($this->view->getSiteUrl() . 'Contactus');
    $translate = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');        
    $form->element->setTranslator($translate);
    $this->view->form = $form;
```

**view**

```
echo $this->form;
```

Comment: please add code in question where you're using gettext adapter and where you're trying to display converted text (i.e form).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set default translator.

```
Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
```

One more alternate way could be:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Contactus();
$translate = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
foreach ($form->getElements() as $key => $element) {
    $element->setTranslator($translate);
}
```

Comment: where do i need to set the default translator ?

Comment: You can set it into your bootstrap file in your `_initTranslate()` method

Comment: protected function _initTranslate() {
        $translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext', APPLICATION_PATH . "/lang/", null, array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY));
        $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
        $registry->set('Zend_Translate', $translate);  
  Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
        $translate->setLocale('ar');
    }

Comment: still facing the same issue

Comment: Have you tried the second way which i have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach to the `Zend_Form` object as a global translator. This will also translate validation error messages :

```
Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
```

Or you can do this :

```
Zend_Validate_Abstract::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

Please see [zend form i18n](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.i18n.html)